# "Disconnecting" an opamp from a potentiometer circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, switches, analog, potentiometer

Last time I asked about changing a sensor (which is a potentiometer) output in various ways. I've decided to go with an opamp and circuit like this:

[image: Snip1]

Now I'm looking for some device that will disconnect the opamp from the potentiometer output based on an ON/OFF (3.3V) signal.

Right now the options I see are:

1. Relay - does exactly that, but I don't want any mechanical parts, also the dimensions are an issue.
2. MOSFET or MOSFET relay - the opamp output must be always higher than Vgs of the particular MOSFET.
3. Bipolar analog switch like the MAX4541 - it has low I/O current and I need higher current capability because of the resistor and potentiometer values.

What else can be used?

Also can anyone tell me about a good alternative to AD8244 unity gain quad buffer? I need only one buffer circuit with a smaller and easier to hand-solder footprint (SOT23-5 maybe.)

@EDIT

I will use MOSFET SSR as suggested in comments. Question regarding AD8244 alternative remains.

Comment: A solid-state relay is the easiest option. If you get the right type, there's no requirements placed on the op amp's output at all.

Comment: @Hearth I know that is the easiest option, but there are several problems: moving part, dimmension, switching speed, reliability. I placed that there just so You know that I've already considered that.

Comment: @Anrzej, Hearth said _solid_ _state_ relay. There are no moving parts. Also, you say you need "higher current capacity". Can you quantify what you mean by "higher" please?

Comment: SSRs have pretty good switching speed and reliability in my experience, and they have no moving parts and while they're not available in the *smallest* packages, you can get them in SOIC packages.

Comment: By higher current I mean something like 200mA. If You can find something that can handle more than 1,5A then I'd be more than happy (I'll remove one circuit). @Hearth Can You give me any particular part number regarding SSR, because I only find "MOSFET" ones, where I see problem with driving potentiometer output LOW. What if potentiometer will be set to 5%, and opamp out voltage to 0.1V? I guess then MOSFET SSR won't work.

Comment: The [CPC1014N](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/ixys-integrated-circuits-division/CPC1014NTR/1973284) perhaps, from IXYS? It's a dual-MOSFET-based one, which is generally the best type as they have low on resistance, work for either DC or AC, are bidirectional, and place no voltage constraints on the load (I'm not sure why you think they do?)

Comment: And if you need more than 1.5 A of current-carrying capacity, look at the [VO14642A](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/vishay-semiconductor-opto-division/VO14642AT/4074374) from Vishay, rated for 2 A with a blocking voltage of up to 60 V, on-state resistance of just 0.25 ohms.

Comment: @Hearth - I have no experience with MOSFET SSRs, and I think like that based on my (little) knowledge about MOSFETs. Both of SSRs You send me are based on N-MOS. Lets now talk just MOSFETs. For N-MOS Vgs is possitive and for example is 1V. I N-MOS SOURCE pin is connected to ground, voltage at gate must be 1V for it to "conduct". In SSRs there are 2 N-MOS with SOURCE pins connected. And for worst case - one drain connected to opamp output at 5V, and second drain connected to pot output which is at 4,5V. ON/OFF signal is 0-3.3V. Then driving that MOSFET connection wont turn it on. Am I right?

Comment: As I said I have no experience with MOSFET SSRs, then I do not know what magic circuitry is inside. If it works like mechanical relay and can switch low voltages (0.1V difference between pins) then that's what I need and we can close that topic. I just need confirmation. Also can anyone recommend unity gain buffer similar to AD8244, but with one circuit and SOT23-5?

Comment: @Anrzej You are not right, because of the way this works; I don't have the energy to explain it in full right now but know that using an optical signal to drive it (which is how SSRs work, the input is current into an LED that shines on optically sensitive semiconductor) means that the voltage doesn't matter.

Comment: @Hearth Ok, I get it, then I will try MOSFET SSR. Hopefully that will work :)

Comment: Your second question is completely unrelated to the first, and should not be part of this question. Ask it as a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a [PhotoMOS relay](https://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/ae/corp/nyumon/relay/photomos.jsp), which uses an LED and photocell to control back-to-back MOSFETs for purely resistive output with no strings attached (unlike conventional SSRs which steal power from the load). It's the closest you can get to a mechanical relay, but much smaller and more reliable.

[image]

In your application there is a large resistance in series and low voltage, so a device like the [AQY282SX](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Panasonic-Industrial-Devices/AQY282SX/?qs=2rFUEsTwVNxaXSXIv3CVhw==) would be fine. It has max. 2.5 Ω 'on' resistance and only needs 5 mA of LED drive current.

Comment: What conventional SSRs are you talking about, just optocouplers? This is the main type of SSR that I use for situations where I need one, and it'd be the first thing I think of if an SSR is mentioned. Though I usually go for one of IXYS's options, personally.

Comment: By 'conventional' I mean AC SSRs like this:- https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13015

Comment: Ah, triac-based ones? Yeah, I've never used those; haven't had much need to. I imagine they can handle more current and voltage than MOSFET based ones. I wonder if there are any SiC-based MOSFET relays yet?